# How to register OWL ontology into Jade agents?

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, agents-jade

I created agents using [Jade](http://jade.tilab.com/) and for ontology development I used OWL and Jena. I want to register ontology in `ServiceDescription`. How can I do this? Should I use an OWL class or a Jena model? I don't know how to set `sd.setOwnership()` and `sd.addOntologies()`. My code:

```
DFAgentDescription dfd = new DFAgentDescription();
ServiceDescription sd = new ServiceDescription();
sd.setType(agentType);
sd.setName(a.getName());
sd.setOwnership(???);
sd.addOntologies(???);
dfd.setName(a.getAID());
dfd.addServices(sd);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Jade, but the documentation for [`addOntologies`](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/domain/FIPAAgentManagement/ServiceDescription.html#addOntologies%28java.lang.String%29) and [`setOwnership`](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/domain/FIPAAgentManagement/ServiceDescription.html#setOwnership%28java.lang.String%29) says that each of these methods take a single `String`, so neither one is expecting an OWL class or a Jena model.

Jade seems to have its own [`Ontology`](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/content/onto/Ontology.html) class, so there may be a disconnect (though I'm not sure) between OWL ontologies and Jade ontologies.  It appears that ontologies get associated with names, and I expect that those registered names are what the `addOntologies` method is expecting.